# Add a Tab character to a URL Link text

Tags: html, css

How can I add a tab character to the link text on a URL

i.e. instead of
`<a href="url">col1 col2</a>`

i have `<a href="url">col1 -TAB SPACE HERE- col2</a>`

The reason for this, is that Im creating a URL list by concatenating columns, and want to space them out correctly, so the url list looks neat.

Ive tried adding a chr(9) into the gap, as well as `&#9;` but it doesn't work. I also know I can target the link with an `a:link {...}` but not sure how to use this to get a tab in there.

Any help much appreciated

thx. Richard

Comment: "*[..] Im creating a URL list by concatenating columns [..]*" - Maybe if you explain how exactly are you doing that, it might help to work it around. Tabs don't work as they are treated as whitespace and coalesced into one. However, if your entire text is inside a `pre`, then the tab entity `&#9;` will work as expected (but break with unbalanced length). Better, still show how you are generating the list and it might be worthwhile to convert that to a table during the process.

Comment: You can do a non-breaking space &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

There are no Tabs in html. Why don't you use a span inside?

```
<a href="url">
    <span class='column'>col1</span>
    <span class='column'>col2</span>
</a>
```

Then add 'column' to your css:

```
.column {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

If you cannot add CSS (you can only modify the text) then you need to add styling inline:

```
<a href="url">
    <span style='width: 50px; float: left;'>col1</span>
    <span style='width: 50px; float: left;'>col2</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Its being constructed as part of an SQL query, and the application builds the link, so I cannot access anything outside of the actual text (i.e. I cannot add a <pre> and </pre> to the outside of the entire link.  Ive tried using <span as per second comment, but it doesn't do anything. (I just tried in in a fiddle).

Comment: @RichardLegge, only adding span is not enough, you need to add some css. If the only thing that you can modify is text, then you will need to add styling directly to spans. See updated answer.